# Character array adds random characters at outputting

Tags: c++, substring, max, c-strings, function-definition

```
cin.get(a, 256);
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
    if(strchr("aeiou", a[i])){
        s = 0;
        strcpy(substr, empty);
        isubstr = 0;
    }
    
    else{
        s++;
        substr[isubstr++] = a[i];
    
        if(s > maax || s == maax){
            maax = s;
            memset(show, 0, 256);
            strcpy(show, substr);
        }

    }
    
}
cout << show;
```

This is the code. It intends to find the longest substring with only consonants and if there are 2+ with the same lenght it outputs the farthest one (closer to the right)

Consider the following sequence:

`jfoapwjfppawefjdsjkflwea`

Splitted by vowels it wold look something like this:

`jf |oa| pwjfpp |a| w |e| fjdsjkflw |ea|`

Notice how "fjdsjkflw" is the largest substring without a vowel. This code outputs just that including some random numbers at the end:

> fjdsjkflwê²a

Why does this happen? Why does it put NULL 3 characters beyond of what it's intended to?

Comment: FYI -- `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)` --  You are calling `strlen(a)` on each iteration of the loop.  That is wasteful.

Comment: Why is it wasteful? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: You do realize that `strlen` has to scan the string, for the null byte?  What if the string is 256 characters?  You will be scanning the string each and every time the loop iterates, making the code actually go for 65536 characters, total.  Compute `strlen` once, store that in a variable, and use that variable in the `for` loop.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if you don't want this overhead, use `std::string` and then you have the `size()` function, which doesn't scan the string looking for a null byte.  You are coding in C++, not C (unless you incorrectly tagged the question), so you really should be using `std::string` anyway.

Comment: _Why does it put NULL 3 characters beyond_ Where in your code is it putting a nul character in `substr`?

Comment: I'm aware, but I'm currently at a high-school level and we only learn character arrays, so we can't deal with `std::string`

Comment: Ahh, they're teaching C++ the wrong way, as pointed in [Kate Gregory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)’s presentation.

Comment: @JustDragos Also, this problem can be solved by using variables that keep track of the starting and ending indices of the currently longest string, i.e. there is no need to `strcpy` anything until after the loop.  After the loop, you simply do a `strncpy` into the final result using the indices that were computed while looping.  Of course, you have to code it, but doing things that way is far faster than calling `strcpy` *within* the loop.

Comment: What did you discover when you used a debugger?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm would you be very kind and indicate me where I should but the null character in substr please?

Comment: Either right after adding a character to it, or before copying it into `show`. (`substr[isubstr] = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you should write a function that finds such a longest sequence of consonants.

You provided an incomplete code so it is difficult to analyze it. For example it is not seen where and how variables `substr` and `empty` used in this call

```
strcpy(substr, empty);
```

are defined and what are their meanings.

Also there are statements like this

```
memset(show, 0, 256);
```

that do not make a sense because for example after this statement there is the statement

```
strcpy(show, substr);
```

So the previous statement is just redundant.

Or for example it seems that one of these variables `s` and `isubstr` is also redundant.

I can suggest the following solution implemented as a function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

std::pair<const char *, size_t> max_consonant_seq( const char *s )
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    
    std::pair<const char *, size_t> p( nullptr, 0 );
    
    do
    {
        size_t n = std::strcspn( s, vowels );
        
        if ( n != 0 && !( n < p.second ) )
        {
            p.first = s;
            p.second = n;
        }
        
        s += n;
        
        s += std::strspn( s, vowels );
    } while ( *s );

    return p;
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "jfoapwjfppawefjdsjkflwea";
    
    auto p = max_consonant_seq( s );
    
    if ( p.second ) std::cout.write( p.first, p.second ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
fjdsjkflw
```

The function returns a pair of objects. The first one specifies the starting pointer of the maximum sequence of consonants in the passed string and the second object specifies the length of the sequence.

All what you need to understand how the function works is to read the description of the two C string functions `strspn` and `strcspn`.